# A minimization chance constrained optimization problem

Tags: probability-distributions, linear-programming, operations-research, random-functions, constraint-programming

$\mathbf{Q}:$ Suppose we have the following chance constrained optimization problem:

\begin{aligned}
            & \text{minimize}
            & & x_1 +x_2\\
            & \text{s.t.}
            & & \mathbf{P}(x_1 + 2x_2\geq\xi_1) \geq\alpha_1\\
            &&& \mathbf{P}(2x_1 + x_2\geq\xi_2) \geq\alpha_2\\
            &&& x_1\geq 0,x_2\geq0
\end{aligned}

where $\xi_1$ and $\xi_2$ are nonnegative random variables which are independent and continuously distributed with a probability distribution function $F_1$ and $F_2$ respectively. Find the optimal solutions $(x_1^*(\alpha_1,\alpha_2),x_2^*(\alpha_1,\alpha_2))$ for any $(\alpha_1,\alpha_2)\in [0,1]\times[0,1]$.

$\mathbf{A}:$ My approach is as follows:

Since the RHS of the constraints are of the form $h=\binom{\xi_1}{\xi_2}$ which is random, the feasible sets of the chance constraints are thus respectively, $K(\alpha_1)=\{(x_1,x_2)|x_1+2x_2\geq F_1^{-1}(\alpha_1)\}$ and $K(\alpha_2)=\{(x_1,x_2)|2x_1+x_2\geq F_2^{-1}(\alpha_2)\}.$

Am I right at till this point with regards to my approach? I am clueless as to how I can proceed further, and I tried simplex but got stuck as well..

Some help will be deeply appreciated!

Comment: The approach is correct. You can even draw the feasible region for this problem.

Comment: @LinAlg Should I continue in that direction, am I right to say that the optimal solution(s) is(are) the intersection/extreme point(intersection region) between the two feasible sets of chance constraints? And also, since $\xi_i$ and $\alpha_i$ are all nonnegative, am I right to assume that $F_i^{-1}$ is also nonnegative?

Comment: For some values of $\alpha$ the feasible set may be a triangle.

Comment: @LinAlg Hmm.. correct me if I am wrong, but should the feasible set be a triangle, that will only apply in the case where the objective is a maximization problem instead? I drew out the feasible sets (2 linear equations with cost vector $c=(1,1)^T$, which is unbounded in the positive direction.

Comment: yes, you are right.

Comment: @LinAlg Thanks for the clarification